# All unique combinations of a column based on another one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
col1 col2
1     1
1     2
1     1
2     1
3     3
3     2
3     1
3     2
3     4
3     1
```

I want to get all the combinations for each value of col2 with everything else but itself group by col1, i.e. achieve the following output:

```
col1 col2 col2_combo
1    1    2
3    3    2
3    3    1
3    3    4
3    2    1
3    2    4
3    1    4
```

I have tried using self join of the table but I can't get a unique result, i.e. a single line for every two values combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are duplicates in the table. So, the first step is to select distinct  values. Well, and then just join the table to itself.

```
with pairs as (select distinct col1, col2 from mytable)
select a.col1, a.col2, b.col2
from pairs a
join pairs b on b.col1 = a.col1 and b.col2 > a.col2
order by a.col1, a.col2, b.col2;
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Quick question. What if col2 was not of type int, therefore b.col2 > a.col2 would not work?

Comment: You can compare decimal values, strings, dates and timestamps as much as integers. It would have to be a very special datatype hence, if `>` were not supported for it.